# program crash while using char*

Tags: c++, c, string, pointers

While running following code, my program crashes unexpectedly!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

    char *str = NULL;
    strcpy(str, "swami");
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

But if I do like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

    char *str;
    strcpy(str, "swami");
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

This code works fine and generates correct output!

I am using gcc compiler(codeblocks IDE). Also, both the codes lead to program crash in DevCpp. Can anyone please explain me why this is so!?

Comment: Before using strcpy, you need to allocate the necessary memory for this. You want the `C` or `C++` solution? The second one does not work fine, it's undefined behavior and you're lucky it works.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot write to `NULL` pointers.

In the second case, it happened that your pointer was randomly initialized to a valid location  in your program's memory. That is why you could do a `strcpy` into it.

Change both programs to have

```
str = malloc(size)
```

or the option with `calloc` before the `strcpy`. (`size` is the size of the space you want to reserve.)

As per comment, you can also change the declaration of `str` to be `char str[6]` (or more).

Last edit: I'll present you this picture showing the memory of your program and the pointers:

[image]

The gray areas and the red one are forbidden (you cannot write or read from them; the top gray one is for kernel memory while the others are spaces not yet reclaimed). The red area at the bottom is the special 0 page. Since `NULL` is `0` your `str = NULL` will point to this and your program will fail.

If you don't assign anything to `str` it will end up pointing randomly. It can still point to the red area or to a grey area -> your program will fail. It could point to a green or blue (both hues) area, making your program work (excepting the cases where it is pointing to a read-only location and you write to it). Allocating area for the pointer makes it point to the green area, enlarging it to the top.

The other option, with `str[6]` enlarges the stack area to bottom. All local variables have space reserved into the stack while all space allocated with `malloc`, `realloc`, `calloc` and other friends goes into the heap.

Lastly, have a look at a [blog article](http://techblog.rosedu.org/arrays-vs-pointers.html) about the difference between `char[]` and `char *`.

PS: If you'd want to use a GNU extension you can look into the `asprintf` function. It would allocate space for a string and write some content there:

```
asprintf(&str, "swami");
```

or

```
asprintf(&str, "%d + %d == %d\n", 1, 2, 3);
```

But, if you want portability, you'd stay away from this function.

Comment: You could also use `char str[6]` and not have to free the memory later.

Comment: Yes, but this would not be the same as using `char *` from the title. I'd add this option as well.

Comment: OK, then use `char buffer[6]; char *str = buffer;`.

Answer (score 4):

In neither version have you allocated memory to copy the string to, so both invoke undefined behaviour. The first one crashes because you explicitly initialised `str` to `NULL`, so the `strcpy` dereferences a `NULL` pointer, that crashes on most systems. In the second, `str` points to arbitrary memory, dereferencing that uninitialised pointer may or may not crash.

Answer (score 2):

Because `NULL` is `#define NULL ((void *)0)` in `<stdlib.h>`. So, you try to write in invalid memory address that make your program crash.

Answer (score 1):

Read this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/)

```
//destination =Pointer to the destination array where the content is to be copied.
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

You're setting destination to NULL, so you're trying to copy source to NULL. That's why it crashes. You should be setting some memory asside to copy the string to instead.

```
int main(){
      char *str=malloc(6);  //enough for "swami"+'\0'
      strcpy(str, "swami");
      printf("%s", str);
      return 0;
```

}

Comment: What's with the anonymous down vote? If answer is not useful leave a comment so it can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy` just copies, not generating space for it.

in the first case you tried to write the string to the beginning of the code segment: not a good idea.

in the second case, you started writing the string to somewhere, and in your case didn't crash do to luck and maybe compiler help.

you should do one of the following:

a. allocate memory: `str = new char[10]` 
b. use `strdup` witch well duplicate the string into a new location.